# Show that there can be an exponential number of maximal cliques in a disk intersection graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

This is Exercise 14 of "Efficient graph representations" (Spinrad), Chapter 3:

> Show that there can be exponentially many maximal cliques in a [disk intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph).

The "canonical" example (as noted [in this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6253da52f238d74a9deb179869341535fed0d474), Theorem 1, and also [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X18301458), page 264) is to place $2n$ points evenly on a circle of radius, say, $1+\varepsilon$ for very small $\varepsilon>0$, then take unit disks centered at each of the $2n$ points. If $\varepsilon$ is small enough, we attain a complete $n$-partite graph with $2^n$ maximal cliques.

This is represented as a disk graph and a straight-line graph in the 2nd source:

[image]

**My question is:** Are there any other examples of disk graphs with exponentially many maximal cliques? (By "other examples" I mean substantively different; not just a small perturbation of the points-on-a-circle example)